# Cannot read property 'id' of null - Javscript, EJS, MongoDB, Express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

My error message is detailed below, which points to the code which I have also listed below.

For an overview, I am trying to create an edit function that allows you to edit a created post. I have listed what I think to be the relevant code files below the error message that is directly below.

I am fairly new to JS and using EJS, a MongoDB and express routes. Any help is greatly apprecaited!

TypeError: C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\views\posts\edit.ejs:17
15|

```
16|       Edit Post
```

> > 17|       ?_method=PUT" method="POST">

```
18|         <%- include('_newpostform') %>

19|       </form>

20|     </div>
```

Cannot read property 'id' of null
at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12), :10:13)
at edit (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at C:\Users\Dobson Dunavant\Desktop\Coding Course\PersonalBlog_JRS\routes\post.js:13:7
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:429:9)

//this is my Posts.js routes file

```
       const express = require("express");
    const Post = require("../models/post");
    const router = express.Router();
    
    // app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    
    router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
      res.render("posts/new", { post: new Post() });
    });
    
    router.get("/edit/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
      res.render("posts/edit", { post: post });
    });
    
    router.get("/:slug", async (req, res) => {
      const post = await Post.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });
      if (post == null) res.redirect("/");
      res.render("posts/show", { post: post });
    });
    
    router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
      let post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        link: req.body.link,
      });
      try {
        post = await post.save();
        res.redirect(`/posts/${post.slug}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("FAILURE");
        res.render("posts/show", { post: post });
      }
    });
    
    router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {});
    
    router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
      await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      res.redirect("/");
    });
    
    module.exports = router;


//**Here is my edit.ejs view file**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Gitfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="new-post-container">
      Edit Post
      <form action="/posts/<% post.id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <%- include('_newpostform') %>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

  <style></style>
</html>
```

Comment: If I were to debug this I would add a console.log(post) at router.get("/edit/:id", ..) just before the res.render to understand better where the problem is hidden. The question is: Is const post an object with an id key? I don't believe the problem lies in the ejs but in the sequelize query return. I would also add a console.log(req.params.id) before the query to check this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

why do you use post-method for updating existing item instead of put?